# Paginate the Firestore Values in Order

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, pagination, google-cloud-firestore

I have this **Cloud Firestore Database** & to access it I use:

```
CollectionReference robDetails = db.collection("ROBOTS").document(RobotA).collection(RobotB);
```

[image]
Each of this "**Connections**" contains two fields (*ConnectionType* & *ConnectionTime*) with values.

I want to load **Connections** ordering by ConnectionTime (the latest at the bottom like shown in the next picture) but only want to show 3 last connections and when user scrolls up show 3 more above the previous ones with the help of SwipeRefreshLayout:

[image: Picture]

The code I currently have to load all the connections like the previous picture is:

```
 private void loadConnections() {
    CollectionReference loadConnect = db.collection("ROBOTS").document(RobotA).collection(RobotB);
    loadConnections.orderBy("connectionTime", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            
            for (DocumentChange documentChange : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                Connections connection = documentChange.getDocument().toObject(Connections.class);

                mConnectionsList.add(connection);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                conRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(mConnectionsList.size() - 1);
                conSwipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**TL;DR:**
I want to load inside my RecyclerView the Part1 first and when the user scrolls up load Part2, when user scrolls up load Part3... with SwipeRefreshLayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I basically came up with a Pagination logic that checks the current date and load the connections happened that day, when user scrolls up for the SwipeRefreshLayout the current date is subtracted by 1 and user is able to get the connections of the previous day:

```
 conSwipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            //subtracting a day
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, numberToSubtract);
            numberToSubtract--;
            SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            String day = s.format(new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis()));

            loadMoreConnections(day);
        }
    });
```

---

```
private void loadMoreMessages(String day) {
    mMessagesList.clear();
    CollectionReference loadConnect = db.collection("ROBOTS").document(RobotA).collection(RobotB);
    loadConnect.orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).startAt(day).endBefore(currentDay).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Error:" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            for (DocumentChange documentChange : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                Connections connection = documentChange.getDocument().toObject(Connections.class);

                mConnectionsList.add(connection);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                conSwipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        }
    });
    loadConnections();
}
```